# 'sliderChanged: unrecognized selector sent to instance'

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uislider

I have created a slider and a text label to display the value of the slider. Both done programmatically:

```
class FilterCell: UITableViewCell {

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    setupViews()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

let slider : UISlider = {
    let slider = UISlider()
    slider.minimumValue = 0
    slider.maximumValue = 50
    slider.value = 50
    slider.continuous = true
    slider.userInteractionEnabled = true
    slider.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return slider
}()

var distanceLabel : UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "Distance: 50km"
    label.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15.0)
    label.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}()

func sliderChanged(sender: UISlider) {
    var sliderValue = sender.value
    distanceLabel.text = "Distance: \(sliderValue)km"
}
}
```

inside my tableview I call the function to change the value of the slider:

```
func tableView(tableView:UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(filterCellId) as! FilterCell
    cell.slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(FilterCell.sliderChanged(_:)), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)

    return cell

}
```

The slider and the label display fine.  When I interact with the slider to change the value, it crashes and 'sliderChanged:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb06d0df040'.

Comment: Next time, when you get a "unrecognized selector" error, include the full error message (as the bit before "`sliderChanged`") tells us something important, namely with what type of object it tried to perform the selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try add target to `cell`, not `self`

```
cell.slider.addTarget(cell, action: #selector(FilterCell.sliderChanged(_:)), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
```

Comment: self always refers to the overseeing class, which in this case is probably a UIViewController.

Comment: Yes, if you place `sliderChanged` method in your view controller, pass `self` instead.

Comment: Yeah I thought so now with what Phuc said.  It's sort of self->cell->uislider.  self can't interact with uislider without interacting with the cell, right?